# How to properly await the completion of multiple async calls from a swagger client in java?

Tags: java, asynchronous, callback, swagger, okhttp

I need to make multiple asynchronous calls through a Swagger generated client, and await the completion of all of the request before continuing. Ideally, I want the request to be made in parallel with each other. My background is in C#, and I think I am looking for the Java equivalent of `Task.WhenAll`.

Here is the Swagger code I am calling:

```
public com.squareup.okhttp.Call getPersonAsync(Integer personid, final ApiCallback<PersonResponse> callback) throws ApiException {

        ProgressResponseBody.ProgressListener progressListener = null;
        ProgressRequestBody.ProgressRequestListener progressRequestListener = null;

        if (callback != null) {
            progressListener = new ProgressResponseBody.ProgressListener() {
                @Override
                public void update(long bytesRead, long contentLength, boolean done) {
                    callback.onDownloadProgress(bytesRead, contentLength, done);
                }
            };

            progressRequestListener = new ProgressRequestBody.ProgressRequestListener() {
                @Override
                public void onRequestProgress(long bytesWritten, long contentLength, boolean done) {
                    callback.onUploadProgress(bytesWritten, contentLength, done);
                }
            };
        }

        com.squareup.okhttp.Call call = getPersonValidateBeforeCall(personid, progressListener, progressRequestListener);
        Type localVarReturnType = new TypeToken<PersonResponse>(){}.getType();
        apiClient.executeAsync(call, localVarReturnType, callback);
        return call;
    }
```

In my code, I have a list of `personIds`, and I need to make a request for each one to get the `PersonResponse` and add it to a list. The `personApi` is a Swagger class that returns an `OkHttp Call` object.

Here is the code I have for it right now:

```
for (int personId: personIds) {

                personApi.getPersonAsync(personId, new ApiCallback<PersonResponse>(){
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(PersonResponseresult, int statusCode, Map<String, List<String>> responseHeaders) {
                        persons.add(result);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(ApiException e, int statusCode, Map<String, List<String>> responseHeaders) {
                       System.out.printf("ApiException Message: %s", e.getMessage());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onUploadProgress(long bytesWritten, long contentLength, boolean done) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub                      
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onDownloadProgress(long bytesRead, long contentLength, boolean done) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub                      
                    }
                  });
            }
```

Right now this code continues executing, but I only want to continue executing the rest of the code after each `PersonResponse` has been added to the list. What is the best way to do that in Java?